# Towards understanding nth_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, nth-element

I am having a difficult time grasping how I should use [`std::nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/), since I am little rusty.

The ref says:

> Rearranges the elements in the range `[first,last)`, in such a way that the element at the nth position is the element that would be in that position in a sorted sequence.

I want to take the n-th element of a subset of a vector, so I thought doing something like this:

```
std::nth_element (v.begin()+start-0, v.begin()+nTh-1, v.begin()+end);
```

would mean to take the subset of the vector `v`, from the `start`, until the `end` (exclusive), and then imagining that this subset is sorted, position the `nTh` element.

It seems that my understanding is off, since this toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);   // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  std::random_shuffle (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());


  std::nth_element (myvector.begin() + 1 - 0, myvector.begin()+5-1, myvector.begin() + 5);
  std::cout <<  *(myvector.begin()+5-1) << std::endl;

  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

prints 9 as the requested element, while I would be expecting 5. What am I missing please?

Comment: The example at cplusplus.com isn't quite concise, use [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: In my experience so far, cppreference has been the better reference in general.

Comment: @Rakete1111 and WhiZTim, thanks for the tip! Baum mit Augen, it's scholastic, but not as friendly and direct for simple things (but as it seems I paid that price).

Comment: How can you possibly "expect 5" (or any other specific value), if you can't even be sure that after `random_shuffle` value `5` is in the subrange covered by your `nth_element` call?

Comment: @gsamaras Am i missing something stupid with my answer? I am actually very confused atm.

Comment: You told it to take a subset of the entire vector, and find the 5th largest element in that subset. That value is unlikely to be 5. (Also, you seem to be having difficulty distinguishing between 1-based and 0-based indexing.)

Comment: @AnT I was misguided by the ref, sorry! Gill Bates, I liked the previous state of your answer. Raymond, more likely trying different stuff around, which gave you that impression, sorry. :/ All clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
std::nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+ 4, myvector.end());
```

instead of :

```
std::nth_element (myvector.begin() + 1, 
                  myvector.begin() + 4, 
                  myvector.begin() + 5);
```

You are shuffling and then calling `nth_element` for only a subsequence. This way you cannot what the returned element should be. If you do it for the whole sequence, then the answer is **5**.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am pointing out that the example he uses has a mistake. This solves the whole question problem, as `nth-element` works as he expects it to. How is this not an answer?

Comment: @PeteBecker It's funny because the *edited version* is literally the original version I posted, before myself editing it. Yes, I am confused too. 
Also, this is as close to an answer as it can get, as there is something wrong with the question itself.

Comment: You replaced your original answer with a snarky non-answer, and that's what I commented on.

Comment: @PeteBecker Because I realized it was his intention to call `nth_element` on a subsequence, and not the whole sequence. The current answer is just weird. No idea why the rollback... No need for unnecessary code. It doesn't make any points.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take the n-th element of a subset of a vector, so I thought
>   doing something like this:
>
> std::nth_element (v.begin()+start-0, v.begin()+nTh-1, v.begin()+end);
>
> would mean to take the subset of the vector v, from the start, until
>   the end (exclusive), and then imagining that this subset is sorted,
>   position the nTh element.

Yes that is true.
But in so doing, any elements in the positions v[0] to v[start-1] and v[end] to v[v.size() - 1] will not be part of the nth_element rearrangement, they will stay where they are. Your start and end as part of nth_element() have excluded these elements from being rearranged.

I think you want

```
std::nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+ 4, myvector.end());
```

which the whole vector is considered (1st and 3rd arguments to nth_element).

This means regardless as to where random_shuffle has shuffled elements

```
std::random_shuffle (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

because nth_element is considerering the whole vector, the 2nd argument to nth_element, the 5th item in myvector if sorted, should be 5. Note, because of the way nth_element works, the previous items will be less than 5 (and in any order) and next items will be more than 5 (and in any order).